# How to get the orientation of an image in php

Tags: php, image

I am doing a project in core php. When i upload images which taken from mobile phone , it will display as inverted images. i am using exif_read_data function to get the orientation of image.and according to its value rotate the image. But i didn't get the orientation of all images.Is there any method to get the orientation of image?

This is the code

```
$exif_data = @exif_read_data($tmp_name);

if(!empty($exif_data['Orientation'])) {

switch($exif_data['Orientation']) {

case 8:

    $image_p = imagerotate($image_p,90,0);
    break;

case 3:

    $image_p = imagerotate($image_p,180,0);

    break;

case 6:

    $image_p = imagerotate($image_p,-90,0);

    break;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can check for the width and height of the image:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('your-image.jpg'); // or other image ext

if ( $width > $height ) {
// Landscape image
}
elseif ( $width < $height ) {
// Portrait
}
else {
// Square
}
```

PS:

> EXIF headers tend to be present in JPEG/TIFF images .. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php).
>
> Resource for `getimagesize()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).